# getElementsByClassName isn't returning all elements

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I'm creating a button that I should highlight certain words within a specified class, but I am having issues with it returning all elements within the class. It will only work if I specify an index, so I'm assuming there may be something wrong with the existing "for loop". Any help is appreciated!

This will work, but only "highlights" the first element in the class, of course:

```
var bodyText = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
bodyText = doHighlight(bodyText, searchArray[i], highlightStartTag, 
highlightEndTag);}

document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML = bodyText;  
return true;
```

This will not work at all:

```
var bodyText = document.getElementsByClassName('test').innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
bodyText = doHighlight(bodyText, searchArray[i], highlightStartTag, 
highlightEndTag);}

document.getElementsByClassName('test').innerHTML = bodyText;  
return true;
```

Comment: Since we have no clue what `doHighlight` does it is kind of hard to help, but the issue is generally, the fact that `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection and you need to use it with a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace multiple words in multiple elements, you need two loops:

```
const testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
for (const element of testElements) {
    for (const search of searchArray) {
        element.innerHTML = doHighlight(element.innerHTML, search, highlightStartTag, highlightEndTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works like a dream. From the other comments, I realize I wasn't clear enough in my explanation, but you read my mind! That's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see `getElementsByClassName` is pluralized (Elements). Indeed a same class can be assigned to multiple HTML elements. You won't find any way to ommit the `[0]` and you shouldn't anyway as it might mean you're getting data from the wrong node. If you need data from a specific element that you can ensure is unique then you need to give it an id and use `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot access `innerHTML` in something which returns an *htmlcollection*

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test').innerHTML
```

Because it's written in plain english: `getElementsByClassName`. **plural**.

`"Elements"`.

with an `"s"` at the end...

meaning it's a (sort of) Array (an [htmlcollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection))